# Teams -Reached catch method Error occurred while executing Code: GeneralException Message: Failed to start/restart provisioning of Team InnerError

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell, provisioning, microsoft-teams

I was trying to create Teams using Powershell script as below

$GroupID = (New-Team -DisplayName $TeamName -AccessType Private -Description $TeamDescription).GroupId

in general this code execute well and it creates the Teams succesfully.but some time once in 100 times i have received the Following error:

*Reached catch method Error occurred while executing 
Code: GeneralException
Message: Failed to start/restart provisioning of Team
InnerError:
  RequestId: d7bba0bc-950b-4a7b-af6b-be80d3a542a7
  DateTimeStamp: 2018-08-03T10:10:58
HttpStatusCode: GeneralException*

want to understand what could be the cause of this issue. if anyone have already faced this issue or any idea how we can resolve this.

Comment: most likely you might be getting throttled 429 exception ? Are you running this in a loop ? If so, add some delay to it using sleep

Comment: its scheduled Activity, but when error occurred only one request was making the call. but Yes even i am suspecting this might be 429 exception with too many requests may be by the user from different application